# Iterator error when listing bucket names in GCP HTTPIterator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Reading a bucket name from google cloud, here is the code

```
storage_client = storage.Client(
project=project, credentials=scoped_credentials)
buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()
for bucket in buckets:
    print(bucket.name)
```

Getting the error :

> ```
>     with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_obj:
> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'
> ```

I checked the debugger and I noticed for

```
buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()
```

I am seeing this error :

> ValueError: ('Iterator has already started',
> <google.api_core.page_iterator.HTTPIterator object at 0x11160ddf0>)

Is there a different way to list buckets in GCP ?

Comment: You are leaving something out in your posted code. Post a minimum example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It works great on my side, with the application default credential. The problem should come from your credential reading